# How to completely remove GCC on CentOS?

Tags: c++, gcc

CentOS: I noticed I have two versions of GCC, one in /usr/bin/gcc (4.4.7) and /usr/local/bin/gcc (4.8). This causes a conflict.

How can I completely remove/purge the 4.4.7? I tried to override but it still causes my other program to crash.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/* /usr/bin/
```

Comment: why not link /usr/bin/gcc to /usr/local/bin/gcc ?

Comment: I tried with the sudo ln above, however it still broken some of my other code. So I guess need to completely replace, I wonder beside the command gcc path, (gcc --version does showing 4.8) it load any shared lib cause problem

Comment: Tag it `linux` maybe someone there will be able to help

Comment: Compile your code then run an `ldd <myprogram>` (you may need sudo) to see which libraries are linked. The compiler is likely finding the newer versions. These should all be removed.